# Derivative of summation across all elements of a matrix

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

Maybe a trivial question but my linear algebra / calculus is not very strong at the moment.

How do I take the derivative wrt a matrix of a summation across all indices, i.e., $\sum_i \sum_j A_{i,j}$?

I am trying to find $\nabla_H F$ where

$$F := \|X - WH\|_2^2 + \lambda \sum_i \sum_j H_{i,j}$$

I understand how the first part of the gradient is derived, but I'm not sure about the second part. I was trying to approach it by realizing

$$\sum_i \sum_j H_{i,j} = e^t H e$$

Where e represents the appropriately sized 1s vector. However, I don't really know how to differentiate that wrt H. Intuitively I would think it works out to $\lambda H$ but I'm not really sure how to step through it.

For context, I'm deriving an algorithm for L1-penalized Non-negative matrix factorization. Normally, the L1-norm does not have a defined gradient, but since all elements of H are $\geq 0$ the L1-norm is just a double summation of all indices. At least, that's what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A convenient product notation for the trace is a colon, i.e. $\,A:B={\rm Tr}(A^TB)$

Write both parts of the objective function in terms of this trace product, then calculate the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 F &= \lambda{\tt\large 11^T}:H + (WH-X):(WH-X) \\
dF &= \lambda{\tt\large 11^T}:dH + 2(WH-X):(W\,dH) \\
   &= \Big(\lambda{\tt\large 11^T} + 2W^T(WH-X)\Big):dH \\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial H}
   &= \lambda{\tt\large 11^T} + 2W^T(WH-X) \\
}$$
Your intuition about using the all-ones vectors was indeed correct.
The cyclic property of the trace permits the terms in a trace product to be rearranged in lots of ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{&A:BC = B^TA:C \;=\; AC^T:B\\&A:B \;=\; B:A}$$

Comment: Ah, thank you @greg !

Answer (score 3):

$$f (\mathrm X) := \sum_i \sum_j x_{ij} = \mathbb 1^\top \mathrm X \,\mathbb 1 = \mbox{tr} \left( \mathbb 1 \mathbb 1^\top \mathrm X \right) =: \left\langle \mathbb 1 \mathbb 1^\top, \mathrm X \right\rangle$$

where $\langle \cdot \, , \cdot \rangle$ denotes the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product). Hence, the gradient of $f$ with respect to $\rm X$ is

$$\nabla_{\rm x} f (\mathrm X) = \mathbb 1 \mathbb 1^\top$$

---

[matrix-calculus](/questions/tagged/matrix-calculus) [scalar-fields](/questions/tagged/scalar-fields) [gradient](/questions/tagged/gradient)